# How to create a score board js for my game

Tags: javascript, html

I'm just starting to learn how to code, I've been working on a game battleship like, I have managed to do most of the things but I can't make my scoreboard work, I would like to know how to do it or what do I need to change in order for making it work.
I've tried adding **var** drawScore but when I add it to my game board disappears.
Also, I speak Spanish so part of my code is in that language.

```js
var rows = 8;
var cols = 8;
var squareSize = 55;
var aciertos=0;
var  errores=0;

var gameBoardContainer = document.getElementById("gameboard");


// Columnas y Filas
for (i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
 for (j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
  
  
  var square = document.createElement("div");
  gameBoardContainer.appendChild(square);
        

   
  square.id = 's' + j + i;   
  
  
  var topPosition = j * squareSize;
  var leftPosition = i * squareSize;   
 
  square.style.top = topPosition + 'px';
  square.style.left = leftPosition + 'px';      
 }
    
}


var hitCount = 0;
var missCount= 0;

/* 

   0 = vacio, 1 = Barco , 2 = Barco Hundiso, 3 = Tiro fallido
*/
var gameBoard = [
    [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
    [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    
    ]


gameBoardContainer.addEventListener("click", fireTorpedo, false);


function fireTorpedo(e) {
    
 if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
       
  var row = e.target.id.substring(1,2);
  var col = e.target.id.substring(2,3);
       

  if (gameBoard[row][col] == 0) {
   e.target.style.backgroundImage = "url('agua.png')";
   // se indica que hay un tiro fallido 
   gameBoard[row][col] = 3;
            missCount++;
   if (missCount == 8) {
    alert("Perdiste");
            errores=errores+1;
            }
   
  // Se cambia el color del cuadro si se da click en uno con barco  y se cambia el valor del cuadro 
  } else if (gameBoard[row][col] == 1) {
   e.target.style.backgroundImage = "url('explo.png')";
   // El valor cambia a 2 si el barco fue "golpeado"
   gameBoard[row][col] = 2;
   
   // Se incrementa el valor si otra parte se ha "golpeado"
   hitCount++;
   if (hitCount == 9) {
    alert("Todas las naves enemigas fueron derrotadas! Ganaste!");
                
   }
   
  // Alerta si el jugador dio click en un cuadro previamente seleccionado
  } else if (gameBoard[row][col] > 1) {
   alert("No gastes tus torpedos! Ya disparaste aquí.");
  }  
        
        // Si se gana o pierde, el juego se reinicia 
        if ((hitCount==9) || (missCount==8))location.href="Battleship.html";
    }
    aciertos==hitCount;
    errores==missCount;
    //Coloca las puntuaciones
    if ((missCount >= 1) ) {

   errores=missCount+1;
   document.puntuacion.errores.value=errores;}
    
     if ((hitCount >= 1)) {
    aciertos=parseInt(document.puntuacion.aciertos.value);
   aciertos=aciertos+1;
   document.puntuacion.aciertos.value=aciertos;};
  
    
    
   
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 60px auto;
    width: 70%;
    max-width: 950px;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 3em;
    font-family:'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'Sans-Serif';
}

p, button, input {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    color: #333;
 margin-bottom:1em;
}

#gameboard {
 position:relative;
 margin:0 auto 2em auto;
 width:500px;
 height:500px;
    
    }
 

#gameboard div {
 position:absolute;
 
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox 1 - 28 */
 box-sizing: border-box;         /* Safari 5.1+, Chrome 10+, Firefox 29+, Opera 7+, IE 8+, Android 4.0+, iOS any */
 background: #add3e6; /* Old browsers */
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
 width:50px;
 height:50px;
}
#gameboard div:hover
{
     color: white;
 background-image: url(mira.png) ;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Battleship</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body background="Mar.jpg">
 
 
<img src="Battleship.jpg" valign="top" height="100%" width="100%" > <br>
 <table border="" cellpadding="9" cellspacing="9" width="99%"  >
  <form name="inicia">
            <tr align= "center" > <p  style="background-color: aliceblue"><b>Instrucciones:</b> <br>
                  Coloque el cursor sobre alguno de los cuadros y haga click;<br>
                  La siguiente imagen <img src="agua.png"  height="5%" width="5%"> aparecerá si en el cuadro no hay un barco <br>Si el cuadro tiene un barco aparecerá la siguiente imagen <img src="explo.png"  height="5%" width="5%">. <br>
                Usted debe encontrar los siguientes 3 barcos: uno de dos posiciones (dos celdas), uno de tres posiciones y uno de 4 posiciones, los barcos pueden estar en posición vertical (|) u horizontal (--)
                <br>
                Si usted comete 8 errores el juego terminará. </p>
            </tr>
   
   <tr align="center">
                <form name="puntuacion">
                <td><p class="texto" style="background: #ffffff">
                    Puntaje  
                    <p class="texto" style="background: #9efaf3">Aciertos</p>
        <input name="aciertos" type="text" size="3" class="campo" readonly="true" disabled="true" style="background: #9efaf3">
        <p class="texto" style="background: #f47f53">Errores</p>
        <input name="errores" type="text" size="3" class="campo" readonly="true" disabled="true" style="background: #f47f53">
                   </td>
                
                
            
                <td>  <div id="gameboard"></div>
 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="battleship.js"></script>
    </td>
            </tr></form></table>
<tr>

 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to the input for the miss counter and the input for the hit counter.
After that you need to set the input value every time a miss or a hit occur.

```
var rows = 8;
var cols = 8;
var squareSize = 55;
var aciertos=0;
var  errores=0;

var gameBoardContainer = document.getElementById("gameboard");

// Here you get the inputs, you need to set the id's in the html code.
var hitCountInputElement = document.getElementById('aciertos');
var missCountInputElement = document.getElementById('errores');

var hitCount = 0;
var missCount= 0;

/*
   0 = vacio, 1 = Barco , 2 = Barco Hundiso, 3 = Tiro fallido
*/
var gameBoard = [
  [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
]

// Columnas y Filas
for (i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
    var square = document.createElement("div");
    gameBoardContainer.appendChild(square);
    square.id = 's' + j + i;

    var topPosition = j * squareSize;
    var leftPosition = i * squareSize;

    square.style.top = topPosition + 'px';
    square.style.left = leftPosition + 'px';
  }
}

gameBoardContainer.addEventListener("click", fireTorpedo, false);


function fireTorpedo(e) {
  if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
    var row = e.target.id.substring(1,2);
    var col = e.target.id.substring(2,3);


    if (gameBoard[row][col] == 0) {
      e.target.style.backgroundImage = "url('agua.png')";
      // se indica que hay un tiro fallido
      gameBoard[row][col] = 3;
      missCount++;
      // Here is where you set the input miss count value
      setMissCountInputElementValue(missCount);
      if (missCount == 8) {
        alert("Perdiste");
        errores=errores+1;
      }

      // Se cambia el color del cuadro si se da click en uno con barco  y se cambia el valor del cuadro
    } else if (gameBoard[row][col] == 1) {
      e.target.style.backgroundImage = "url('explo.png')";
      // El valor cambia a 2 si el barco fue "golpeado"
      gameBoard[row][col] = 2;

      // Se incrementa el valor si otra parte se ha "golpeado"
      hitCount++;
      // Here is where you set the input hit count value
      setHitCountInputElementValue(hitCount);
      if (hitCount == 9) {
        alert("Todas las naves enemigas fueron derrotadas! Ganaste!");
      }

      // Alerta si el jugador dio click en un cuadro previamente seleccionado
    } else if (gameBoard[row][col] > 1) {
      alert("No gastes tus torpedos! Ya disparaste aquí.");
    }

    // Si se gana o pierde, el juego se reinicia
    if ((hitCount==9) || (missCount==8)) {
      location.href="Battleship.html"
    };
  }

  aciertos==hitCount;
  errores==missCount;

  //Coloca las puntuaciones
  if ((missCount >= 1) ) {
    errores=missCount+1;
    document.puntuacion.errores.value=errores;
  }

  if ((hitCount >= 1)) {
    aciertos=parseInt(document.puntuacion.aciertos.value);
    aciertos=aciertos+1;
    document.puntuacion.aciertos.value=aciertos;
  }
}

function setHitCountInputElementValue (hitCount) {
  hitCountInputElement.value = hitCount;
}

function setMissCountInputElementValue (missCount) {
  missCountInputElement.value = missCount;
}
```